# Is it possible to convert all straight quotes to curly quotes in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to turn:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| It's time to go home | What's your name |
| He said "nothing" | "I got you" |

into:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| It’s time to go home | What’s your name |
| He said “nothing” | “I got you” |

Is there any way I can achieve that in Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, use REGEXREPLACE()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regexreplace()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245). To replace many patterns, use [reduce()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597), like this:

```
=let( 
  text, A1:B, 
  replaceWhat, { "'", "(^|\W)""(\w)", "(\w)""(\W|$)" }, 
  replaceWith, { "’", "$1“$2", "$1”$2" }, 
  replaceAll_, lambda(what, with, lambda(t, 
    reduce(t, sequence(counta(what)), lambda(acc, i, 
      regexreplace(acc, index(tocol(what, 2), i), index(tocol(with, 2), i)) 
    )) 
  )), 
  map(text, replaceAll_(replaceWhat, replaceWith)) 
)
```

With data like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| It's time to go home | What's your name |
| He said "nothing" | "I got you" |

...the results look like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| It’s time to go home | What’s your name |
| He said “nothing” | “I got you” |

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).